# In Ruby, how can one make a weighted random selection by least weight?

Tags: ruby, random, weighted

If I have the array :

`ar = [1,3,5,3,6,1,4,6,7,6,6,6,6,6]`

I could reduce this to the amount of occurrences :

`counts = {1=>2, 3=>2, 5=>1, 6=>7, 4=>1, 7=>1}`

Now I would like to choose *at random* with the least used number in `ar` being *more* weighted

I understand how I could easily make a weighted random choice based on most commonly used number, but not its inverse.

Comment: Your array has `14` elements, two of which are `1`. So what should the probability be of picking `1`? How do you want to apply the weighting?

Comment: The trivial answer would be to simply invert the weights and use an existing mechanism. There are more-complex (and direct) mechanisms, but they're all likely similar in the long run.

Comment: What about reverting the weights order (making them negative or dividing 1 by weights etc - any transformation that reverts the order should work) and solving the task you already understand the solution for?

Comment: This all depends what weighting is intended. Should it be **twice as likely** to pick a `5` than a `1`?

Comment: Pick any monotonically decreasing function, compute its values at given frequences, consider it relative probabilities, normalize, sample.

Comment: Nothing can be said until you clarify the question. It needs to be precise and unambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this would work for you:

```
arr = [1,3,5,3,6,1,4,6,7,6,6,6,6,6]

arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values{|v| arr.size / v.size}.flat_map do |k,v| 
 [k] * v
end.sample
```

We group the elements and count them then we create a new `Array` with the number of elements inverted to favor the lesser occurrences.  e.g.

```
arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values{|v| arr.size / v.size}.flat_map do |k,v| 
 [k] * v
end.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)
#=> {1=>7, 3=>7, 5=>14, 6=>2, 4=>14, 7=>14}
```

Since 5 occurred once originally it now occurs 14 times (same with 4 and 7). 
So 5,4, and 7 have equal likelihood of being chosen and are each twice as likely as 1 and 3 which occured twice and 7 times as likely as 6.

Also maybe something like this might be more efficient

```
grouping =arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size).
scale = grouping.values.uniq.reduce(&:lcm)

grouping.flat_map do |k, v|
  [k]  * (scale / v)
end.sample
```

Comment: Yah well done. That was an excellent Ruby response. I have never heard of `&:itself` before

Comment: @Trip Just a small note: the proposed solution is concise and elegant but if input array contains unique values only it will dramatically increase (square) the array size before trying to sample a random value from it. Try creating an input array like `arr = (0..999).map { rand(100000) }` and then apply the code above to it - you will get an array of approximately 1M records to sample from. For an array with just 50K unique items taking weighted random value using this method requires almost 10 seconds on my laptop...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I agree we could definitely go with a more performant solution for sure

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov we can determine the lcm of the group sizes to make this more efficient now your code returns instantly.

Comment: YOu could abstract it further by making call to monotonically decreasing function. You use inverse function, but actually any one could do the job. Say, 1/exp(frequency) will make selection probabilities very sharp, while 1/log(1+frequency) would be lenient one... Compute this function for all frequences, make it relative probabilities, normalize, sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an algorithm for making a random weighted choice, one option to swap the weight can be as follows.

```
grouping = ar.group_by { |n| n }.transform_values(&:size)
#=> {1=>2, 3=>2, 5=>1, 6=>7, 4=>1, 7=>1}
weights = grouping.values.uniq.sort
#=> [1, 2, 7]
reverse_mapping = weights.zip(weights.reverse).to_h
#=> {1=>7, 2=>2, 7=>1}
grouping.transform_values{ |v| reverse_mapping[v] }
#=> {1=>2, 3=>2, 5=>7, 6=>1, 4=>7, 7=>7}
```

That's the idea.

---

Can be refactored to be more Rubyish:

```
res = ar.group_by { |n| n }.transform_values(&:size).then do |h|
  rev_map = h.values.uniq.sort.then { |w| w.zip(w.reverse).to_h }
  h.transform_values{ |v| rev_map[v] }
end

#=> {1=>2, 3=>2, 5=>7, 6=>1, 4=>7, 7=>7}
```

Comment: You can use &:itself